# Apim Analytics don´t allow me to start 'worker' and 'dashboard' nodes at the same time

Tags: wso2, analytics, api-manager

Cenario: 
API Manager and APIM ANalytics 2.6.0 running at the same machine.

Issue: after start the APIM worker node, the APIM Dashboard node don't start and give to me a lot of WARNs as follow:

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_211-amd64
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /opt/wso2am-analytics
RUNTIME_HOME environment variable is set to /opt/wso2am-analytics/wso2/dashboard
[2019-04-26 16:16:20,189]  INFORMAÇÕES {org.wso2.carbon.launcher.extensions.OSGiLibBundleDeployerUtils updateOSGiLib} - Successfully updated the OSGi bundle information of Carbon Runtime: dashboard
osgi> [2019-04-26 16:16:22,006]  INFO {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.websocket.EndpointsRegistryImpl} - Endpoint Registered : /websocket-provider/{topic}
[2019-04-26 16:16:22,559]  INFO {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.websocket.WebSocketServerSC} - All required capabilities are available of WebSocket service component is available.
[2019-04-26 16:16:22,571]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.core.config.model.JmxReporterConfig} - Creating JMX reporter for Metrics with domain 'org.wso2.carbon.metrics'
[2019-04-26 16:16:22,599]  INFO {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MicroservicesServerSC} - All microservices are available
[2019-04-26 16:16:22,599]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.core.reporter.impl.AbstractReporter} - Started JMX reporter for Metrics
[2019-04-26 16:16:22,669]  INFO {org.wso2.msf4j.analytics.metrics.MetricsComponent} - Metrics Component is activated
[2019-04-26 16:16:22,673]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.internal.DataAgentDS} - Successfully deployed Agent Server
[2019-04-26 16:16:22,742]  INFO {org.wso2.transport.http.netty.listener.ServerConnectorBootstrap$HTTPServerConnector} - HTTP(S) Interface starting on host 0.0.0.0 and port 9643
[2019-04-26 16:17:22,535]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupOrderResolver} - Startup component carbon-deployment-service from bundle(org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine:5.2.0) is in the pending state until Capability org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.Deployer from bundle(org.wso2.carbon.uiserver:0.19.5) is available as an OSGi service. Refer the Startup Order Resolver documentation for information.
[2019-04-26 16:17:22,536]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupOrderResolver} - Startup component carbon-ui-server-startup-listener from bundle(org.wso2.carbon.uiserver:0.19.5) is in the pending state, because of the Capability org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.spi.RestApiProvider from bundle(org.wso2.carbon.business.rules.core:2.0.423). If you've registered this capability as an OSGi service, you need to declare it using the Carbon-Component manifest header. Refer the Startup Order Resolver documentation for information.
[2019-04-26 16:17:22,536]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupOrderResolver} - Startup component carbon-ui-server-startup-listener from bundle(org.wso2.carbon.uiserver:0.19.5) is in the pending state, because of the Capability org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.spi.RestApiProvider from bundle(org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.api:4.0.38). If you've registered this capability as an OSGi service, you need to declare it using the Carbon-Component manifest header. Refer the Startup Order Resolver documentation for information.
[2019-04-26 16:17:22,536]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupOrderResolver} - Startup component carbon-ui-server-startup-listener from bundle(org.wso2.carbon.uiserver:0.19.5) is in the pending state until Capability org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.spi.RestApiProvider from bundle(org.wso2.carbon.data.provider:2.0.423) is available as an OSGi service. Refer the Startup Order Resolver documentation for information.
[2019-04-26 16:17:22,536]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupOrderResolver} - Startup component carbon-ui-server-startup-listener from bundle(org.wso2.carbon.uiserver:0.19.5) is in the pending state until Capability org.wso2.carbon.uiserver.spi.RestApiProvider from bundle(org.wso2.carbon.status.dashboard.core:2.0.423) is available as an OSGi service. Refer the Startup Order Resolver documentation for information.
[2019-04-26 16:17:22,537]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupOrderResolver} - Startup component sp-idp-service from bundle(org.wso2.carbon.analytics.idp.client:6.0.70) is in the pending state, because of the Capability org.wso2.carbon.analytics.idp.client.core.spi.IdPClientFactory from bundle(org.wso2.carbon.analytics.idp.client:6.0.70). If you've registered this capability as an OSGi service, you need to declare it using the Carbon-Component manifest header. Refer the Startup Order Resolver documentation for information.
[2019-04-26 16:17:22,537]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupOrderResolver} - Startup component sp-idp-service from bundle(org.wso2.carbon.analytics.idp.client:6.0.70) is in the pending state until Capability org.wso2.carbon.analytics.idp.client.core.spi.IdPClientFactory from bundle(org.wso2.carbon.analytics.idp.client:6.0.70) is available as an OSGi service. Refer the Startup Order Resolver documentation for information.
```

If I start the Dashboard node first, the same log is presentd in the start of worker node.

I just follow th default configuration https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+APIM+Analytics
and https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Enabling+API-M+Analytics+Features+in+WSO2+Stream+Processor

Answer (score 2):

You have to start

1. APIM Analytics worker profile
2. APIM server
3. APIM Analytics dashboard profile,

one after another as in the order mentioned.

Here you have to wait until the first profile is fully started to start the next one.
That way all the OSGi bundles will be started according to the order in the [Startup order resolver documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon500/Resolving+the+Startup+Order).